# Convert Binary to Byte[] array

Tags: c#, asp.net, database

How can i convert binary data stored in my database field to Byte[] array?

simply casting binary as byte[] is not working

```
context.Response.BinaryWrite((byte[])images);
```

Comment: What's the exact type of `images`?

Comment: Are you getting the binary string?

Comment: What is the data type of the database object?

Comment: datatype of image VarBinary(Max)

Comment: VarBinary(max) is no C# data type...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If images is a single record of type Binary then calling toArray should work

```
 context.Response.BinaryWrite(images.toArray());
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public byte[] FileToByteArray(string _FileName)    
{

        byte[] _Buffer = null;

       try
        {
            // Open file for reading
            System.IO.FileStream _FileStream = new System.IO.FileStream(_FileName, System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read);

            // attach filestream to binary reader
            System.IO.BinaryReader _BinaryReader = new System.IO.BinaryReader(_FileStream);

            // get total byte length of the file
            long _TotalBytes = new System.IO.FileInfo(_FileName).Length;

            // read entire file into buffer
            _Buffer = _BinaryReader.ReadBytes((Int32)_TotalBytes);

            // close file reader
            _FileStream.Close();
            _FileStream.Dispose();
            _BinaryReader.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception _Exception)
        {
            // Error
            Console.WriteLine("Exception caught in process: {0}", _Exception.ToString());
        }

        return _Buffer;
}
```