# How can I solve "Cannot convert 'system.data.datacolumn' to 'byte[]'"?

Tags: c#, sql, windows-forms-designer

So I am trying to show an image from my SQL server in a PictureBox, but when I try to convert the system.data.datacolumn to a byte[] I get the following error: "Cannot convert 'system.data.datacolumn' to 'byte[]'". I have searched for 2 hours how to solve it, but I have not found anything, hope you can help me :).

My code has a lot of different classes, so I am gonna try to explain it as good as possible.

```
// you have the "herramientas" method bellow, is where I make the connection.
DataSet dataSet = Biblioteca.Herramientas(string.Format("SELECT * FROM Producto"));


//The next two lines select one row from the table "Image" where the image is stored
int id_image = Convert.ToInt16(dataSet.Tables[0].Rows[contador]["id_Image"]);
DataSet dataset_Image = Biblioteca.Herramientas(string.Format("SELECT * FROM Image WHERE id_Image = "+ id_image));

//**here I have the problem**
byte[] array = (byte[])dataset_Image.Tables[0].Columns["image"];

// It let me convert it to string
dataset_Image.Tables[0].columns["image"].tostring();
```

This is the method where I make the connection, is not really relevant, but maybe it is helpful for you

```
public static DataSet Herramientas (string cdm)
{
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=PracticaSQL;Integrated Security=True");
    DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cdm, connection);
    adapter.Fill(dataSet);
    connection.Close();
    return dataSet;
}
```

And lastly this is how I add pictures in my table in sql

```
--the "image" column in the table "Image" is not an image datatype, but varbinary(MAX)
insert into Image select * from openrowset (bulk 'here goes the image directory', single_blob) as image
```

And that is all the code, I hope the solution is not too difficult, and if you need anything more just ask it.
Thank you all for your time, I hope you have a good day :D.

Comment: This answer may be of help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6583009/convert-binary-to-byte-array

Comment: I think the problem is that in `Image` query you don't dereference the row like you did in `Producto` query.

Comment: @orhtej2 I do use the dereference operator (*) if that is what you mean, if you mean that I don't have to use it, then it gives me an error if I don't specify what it has to select

Comment: Try `byte[] array = dataset_Image.Tables[0].Rows[0].Field<byte[]>(0);` `0` at the end meaning the column you are going after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

byte[] array = dataset_Image.Tables[0].Rows[0].Field(0); 0 at the end meaning the column you are going after (solution offered by @Çöđěxěŕ).